# How to reach Value if value is in form of uuid in Postman

Tags: java, api, testing, automated-tests, postman

The response body is

```
{
    "name": "1",
    "widgets": {
        "ijklmnop-abcd-1234-91f0-f51f1825b788": {
            "id": "ijklmnop-abcd-1234-91f0-f51f1825b788",
            "width": 1760,
            "content": {
                "params": {
                    "data": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "aggregations": [
                    ],
                    "valueTypes": [
                        "none"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "abcdefgh-5678-90ds-ae27-abae62385a55": {
            "id": "abcdefgh-5678-90ds-ae27-abae62385a55",
            "width": 1240,
            "content": {
                "params": {
                    "data": 1,
                    "values": [],
                    "timestamps": []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want to extract as well as check id and other parameters inside abcdefgh-5678-90ds-ae27-abae62385a55(uuid) in the body?

Comment: Try using ```jsonObject.keys()``` and get each key and store them in list and then again run through the json object

Comment: This would create an array and log those values to the console `console.log(_.keys(pm.response.json().widgets));`